# Matlab - graph points paint

Tags: matlab, graph, montecarlo

I am using Monte Carlo Simulation to calculate the probability of failure and I want to paint the points which represents the failure (in red) in the scatter histogram. I can I do it? The code is below

```
% Histograms

hist(S,20)

hold on

hist(R,40)

set(findobj('Type','patch'),'Facecolor','none','Edgecolor','black')

set(gca,'Fontsize',18,'Fontname','euclid')

xlabel('R & S')


figure

scatterhist(R,S)

xlabel('R'),ylabel('S')
```

Comment: How is "failure" defined? Is it given by `I` equal to 1?

Comment: Failure is defined by variable I, which represents the cases where R is smaller than S. Hope I could help

Comment: Z is a vector that saves all the probability of failure (pf). Then all cases of pf which is smaller than 1, that represents the failure (I<0) it counts to pf. In the scatter graph I would like to paint these points with red colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your line

> `scatterhist(R,S)`

by the following:

```
h_axes = scatterhist(R, S); %// get handles to the three axes 
h_values = get(h_axes(1), 'children'); %// get handle to plotted data
set(h_values, 'XData', R(~I), 'YData', S(~I)); %// remove failures
axes(h_axes(1))
hold on
plot(R(I), S(I), 'ro'); %// put failures back, in red
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put the failure point in the front of the graph? Instead of in the back? Thanks

Comment: Or rotate both graph's (FDP) so the base of them face the axis? Thanks a lot

Comment: For the first question: The failure points are already on top. If you to make it stand out more, replace my last line by `plot(R(I), S(I), 'r.', 'markersize', 20)`

Comment: Just change the `'YDir'` or `'XDir'` property of their axes to `'reverse'`: that is, `set(h_axes(2), 'YDir', 'Reverse'), set(h_axes(3), 'XDir', 'Reverse')`

Comment: Only one thing: the left histogram didnt rotate.

`figure
set(gcf,'color','w');
h_axes = scatterhist(R, S); %// get handles to the three axes 
h_values = get(h_axes(1), 'children'); %// get handle to plotted data
set(h_values, 'XData', R(~I), 'YData', S(~I)); %// remove failures
axes(h_axes(1))
set(h_axes(2), 'YDir', 'Reverse')
set(h_axes(3), 'XDir', 'Reverse')
hold on
plot(R(I), S(I), 'r.', 'markersize', 20); %// put failures back, in red
xlabel('R'),ylabel('S')`

This is the code I have. Thanks again and sorry to bother!

Comment: Well, it does for me. The line responsible for that is `set(h_axes(3), 'XDir', 'Reverse')`

Comment: I dont know then. The left graph doesnt rotate. I mean, it's base should be facing the yy axis instead of its peak. I dont know if I am explaining myself in the proper way.

Comment: Yes, I get what you mean. It should work.  Try this code alone: `h_axes = scatterhist(R, S); set(h_axes(3), 'XDir', 'Reverse')`. Does it work?

Comment: something like this: `figure
set(gcf,'color','w');
h_axes = scatterhist(R, S); %// get handles to the three axes 
h_values = get(h_axes(1), 'children'); %// get handle to plotted data
set(h_values, 'XData', R(~I), 'YData', S(~I)); %// remove failures
h_axes = scatterhist(R, S);
set(h_axes(3), 'XDir', 'Reverse')
hold on
plot(R(I), S(I), 'r.', 'markersize', 20); %// put failures back, in red
xlabel('R'),ylabel('S')` Didn't work. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Please do try the code in my last comnent and tell me if it works

Comment: Just this: `figure
h_axes = scatterhist(R, S); set(h_axes(3), 'XDir', 'Reverse')` didn't work. Sorry mate.

Comment: Well, it works for me. I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe try `set(h_axes(1), 'XDir', 'Reverse')` (perhaps axis ordering is different in your Matlab version)

Comment: WORKED! :) Thanks a lot mate! And to bother you so much! :) Regards

Comment: :-) I learned something along the way too: not to trust axis ordering produced by Matlab functions

Comment: Funny joke! :) At least, all the effort was rewarded for the both of us! ;) Regards